# Mixing Programming Languages in the "Code Blocks" IDE?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, codeblocks

Is there a way I can mix, for example, C# code and C++ code in the [Code Blocks IDE](http://www.codeblocks.org/)?

If I'm not clear enough, this is basically about adding code files from another language to C++.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You might be looking for something like a DLL, which would allow you to call C++ functions from C# code, though it's a bit harder to go the other way.

Comment: Look up foreign function interface.

Comment: According to the Code::Block forums, "C# is currently not supported in Code::Blocks", so I do not see how you could write C# with Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Not in Code::Blocks, no. If you were looking for a free ide you should try monodevelop or sharpdevelop.